# How to switch elements for any given list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Lets say I have a list: `["5", "6", "4", "3"]`

What I want to do is replace any char `"5"` with `"6"` and replace `"6"` with `"5"`.

So the list would look like this in the end:

```
["6", "5", "4", "3"]
```

I want to do this for all lists that may be inputted. This means that not all lists will have the elements `"5"` and `"6"` in them, but I want to switch the `5`'s and the `6`'s for the lists that do.

Note: The elements in the list are string elements. Not integers.

I've been thinking of using `if` statements and `.replace()` but that changes the `5` and `6`, but then changes it back.

Examples:

```
if "5" in list1:
    list1.replace("5", "6")
if "6" in list1:
    list1.replace("6", "5")
```

As you can see, that just replaces it back. It doesn't work. It would be great if someone could help me solve this.

Note: If the element is `"1532"` in a list, the `5` in that should also be replaced with a string. Vice versa for `6`'s as well.

Another Example:

```
firstlist = ["125", "673", "222", "65"]`
```

Output:

```
firstlist = ["126", "573", "222", "56"]
```

Comment: What if there aren't an equal number of 5s and 6s? Say, `[1,5,6,6]`?

Comment: @ggorlen It doesn't matter the number of 5's and 6's. You should just replace those elements with eachother.

Comment: OK, so that would be `[1,6,5,5]` then.

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the assumption there are no underscores and tabs in your lists, this can work:

```
>>> list1 = ["126", "573", "222", "56"]
>>> str1 = "\t".join(list1)
>>> str1.replace("5", "_").replace("6", "5").replace("_", "6").split('\t')
['125', '673', '222', '65']
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a general function that performs the swaps by iterating over chars in strings and keying into a dict to locate the partner for each swappable element. This technique can scale to any number of arbitrary swaps you want to include; just make the `swaps` dict a parameter instead of `x` and `y`.

```
>>> def swap_all(lst, x, y):
...     swaps = {x: y, y: x}
...     return ["".join(swaps.get(c, c) for c in e) for e in lst]
...
>>> swap_all(["125", "64", "1", "5", "4", "65", "6"], "5", "6")
             ['126', '54', '1', '6', '4', '56', '5']
```

Answer (score 2):

I based myself on the solution of @0 0:

```
t = ['254', '556', '056', '30565']
[a.replace('5', '-').replace('6', '5').replace('-', '6') for a in t]
Output:
['264', '665', '065', '30656']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for and replace each character like this:

```py
firstlist = ["125", "673", "222", "65"]

def switch(a, b, values):
    output = []
    for value_str in values:
        output.append(
            ''.join(
                a if b == v else b if a == v else v for v in value_str
            )
        )
    return output

print(switch('5', '6', firstlist))

>>> ['126', '573', '222', '56']
```