# How do you swap integers in a list when those integers may repeat

Tags: python, list, swap

My list contains random integers in no order. I want to swap elements while keeping the order of the list intact.

```
ran=[1,1,2,1]
```

And I want to swap say 1 and 2:

```
swap(ran,1,2)
output:
2212
```

or

```
ran=[3,3,1,2]
swap(ran,1,3)
output:
1132
```

I tried a swap function, but I know my iteration logic isn't very good.

```
def swap(c,x,y):

arr=[]

for i, v in enumerate(c):
        if v==x or v==y:
            for j,v2 in enumerate(c):
                if v2==y or v2==x:
                    arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
```

This just changes one of the values.

The problem is not knowing which index has been changed already.

Comment: It looks like you aren't actually swapping specific elements; you're just changing all the `x`s to `y`s and vice-versa. What happens if a `y` doesn't exist? e.g. should `swap([1, 1, 1], 1, 2)` produce `[2, 2, 2]`?

Comment: Is a swap for the same value valid? I.e. if the swap method suggests a swap of `1` for `1` is that ok? Or must every number be mapped to something else?

Comment: This almost-exact question was asked a few hours ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60355729/how-to-switch-elements-for-any-given-list/60355853#60355853. Is there a competition going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The examples you gave suggest the process you want isn't really a "swap" of individual elements as such, but more like a bi-directional "search and replace". If that's what's needed, a much simpler loop would work:

```py
def swap(c, x, y):
  for i, v in enumerate(c):
    if v == x:
      c[i] = y
    elif v == y:
      c[i] = x
```

Comment: The simplicity makes this response a stand-out.  Plus, it is efficient with regard to memory usage - no new list is created.

Comment: I like this too and it does save the dict allocation, but if you want to scale/generalize to arbitrarily large numbers of swaps, writing a giant `if`-`else` with dozens of options isn't much fun.

Comment: Ok it looks like I was banging my head on search looking for swap when I wanted a search and replace. Thanks very much to cschatz and everyone else.

Answer (score 3):

Use a dict to encode the swapping logic and index into it with `get(e, e)`. Any non-swappable elements that aren't in the dict will be left alone.

```
>>> def swap(lst, x, y):
...     swaps = {x: y, y: x}
...     return [swaps.get(e, e) for e in lst]
...
>>> swap([1, 1, 2, 1], 1, 2)
[2, 2, 1, 2]
```

You can generalize this by letting the caller pass in a dictionary to specify the swaps. Here's a [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60355729/how-to-switch-elements-for-any-given-list).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this:

```
def swap(lst,x,y):
    ret = lst
    for e in range(0,length(lst)):
        if x == lst[e]:
            ret[e] = y
        if y == lst[e]:
            ret[e] = x
    return ret
```